# What is the proper format to use when defining a date-effective attribute in a DRL using DATE & TIME

Tags: drools

Drools documentation states the following:

> string containing a date and time definition. The rule can be activated only if the current date and time is after a date-effective attribute.

> Example: date-effective "4-Sep-2018"

(https://docs.drools.org/7.74.1.Final/drools-docs/html_single/index.html)

I am having trouble getting version 7.49 to understand the date and time combination. Only date works without issues

I have tried using the following format to no success: date-effective "4-Sep-2018 08:00"

Is anyone able to provide some guidance? I have done some research but seeing a lot of custom logic needed or adding an additional evaluation to our where clauses which I would like to avoid.

Answer (score 0):

Drools is using the [DateUtils](https://github.com/kiegroup/drools/blob/main/drools-util/src/main/java/org/drools/util/DateUtils.java) class to parse the `date-effective` attribute of the rules.

This class uses a `DATE_FORMAT_MASK` String as the pattern used to convert `Strings` into `Dates`. The default value is `d-MMM-yyyy` and does not allow time.
You should be able to change this pattern by setting the `drools.dateformat` system variable.

Disclaimer: I haven't tried this and it may be the case that this pattern is also used for other `String` -> `Date` conversions.

Comment: Awesome, will have to give that a go. Will accept if it works out.